# Why is req.cookie.token_name not working?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, cookies, jwt

I was building authentication for a website
and the req.cookie was returning undefined. Can I know what's wrong with that?

this is my server code

and I imported the auth file here

```
app.get("/", auth, (req, res) => {
        res.render("index")
})
```

this is my auth.js file

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")
const Register = require("../models/registration")
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser")
const express = require("express")

const app = express()

app.use(cookieParser())

const auth = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const token = req.cookie.token_name
        console.log(token)
        const verifyUser = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY)
        next()
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.status(401).send(error)
    }
}

module.exports = auth
```

if required this is my login code as well but yeah i verified its storing cookies on the browser

```
app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const password = req.body.password
        const email = req.body.email
        
        const user = await Register.findOne({ email: email })
        
        const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
        
        const token = await user.generateAuthenticationToken()
        
        res.cookie('jwt', token, {
            maxAge: 600*1000,
            httpOnly: true,
        })
        
        if (isMatch) {
            res.redirect("/")
        } else {
            res.send("Invalid Credentials")
        }
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).send(error)
    }
})
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The question title speaks of `req.cookie.token_name`, but the word `token_name` occurs nowhere in your code.

Comment: token_name is jwt

Comment: Perhaps you want to write `const token = req.cookie.token_name`?

Comment: yup i missed it

Comment: that was something i did for debugging but now fixed

Comment: The field is called [`req.cookies`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.cookies), not `req.cookie`.